# Alterar o atributo do HTML no option com JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, html-select, option

Estou tentando alterar o valor do campo no **select** com o **option** para "disabled" mas apenas quando o usuário clicar no campo de input.

Vejam a imagem para entender melhor:
[image: formulario com o select option]

Eu quero exatamente deixar desabilitado o primeiro "option" apenas quando o usuario clicar no campo, estou tentando isso, mas não da certo, estou começando a ver Jquery Agora.

```
<select id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Categoria: *">
    <option value="categoria" id="#cat">Categoria: *</option>
    <option value="buracos nas ruas">Buracos nas ruas</option>
    <option value="esgoto a ceu aberto">Esgoto a céu aberto</option>
    <option value="lixo em local proibido">Lixo em local proibido</option>
    <option value="falta de iluminação">Falta de iluminação</option>
    <option value="outros">Outros</option>
</select>


$('label select option').click(function(){
    $('#cat').html('<option  disabled >Categoria: *</option>');
});
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço imensamente.

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo errado. A primeira `option` você pode deixar com `value=""` e colocar o `id="cat"` (que também está errado: `id="#cat"`) e `name="categoria"` no `select`, ficando assim:

```html
<select id="cat" name="categoria" class="form-input">
    <option value="">Categoria: *</option>
    <option value="buracos nas ruas">Buracos nas ruas</option>
    <option value="esgoto a ceu aberto">Esgoto a céu aberto</option>
    <option value="lixo em local proibido">Lixo em local proibido</option>
    <option value="falta de iluminação">Falta de iluminação</option>
    <option value="outros">Outros</option>
</select>
```

Esse `placeholder="Categoria: *"` também não precisa. A primeira `option` é que fará o papel do "placeholder".

No tocante a desabilitar a primeira `option` ao clicar no `select`, pode fazer desta forma:

```js
// seleciono o select com id="cat"
// com dois eventos: focus e blur
$('#cat').on('focus blur', function(e){
    $('option:first', this) // selecione a primeira option
    .prop('disabled', e.type == 'focus' ? true : false);
    // desabilito se o evento for focus
    // habilito se o evento for blur
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cat" name="categoria" class="form-input" placeholder="Categoria: *">
    <option value="">Categoria: *</option>
    <option value="buracos nas ruas">Buracos nas ruas</option>
    <option value="esgoto a ceu aberto">Esgoto a céu aberto</option>
    <option value="lixo em local proibido">Lixo em local proibido</option>
    <option value="falta de iluminação">Falta de iluminação</option>
    <option value="outros">Outros</option>
</select>
```